# Download two table in two panel with one download button in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, download, ss

I am using the download button in R shiny, is it possible to download two different tables in different tabPanel(Page A and Page B)?

**I think my problem is:
If I can let the server know which tab is selected by the user? and then ther server will change the table of the download button based on the tab page.**

I can not zip the two table into an excel because the user want the two table to be seperated.

Thanks for your help.

If the user is in page A: export output_batch_predict.xlsx

If the user is in page B: export part.xlsx

This is the code for the download button:

```
ui:

tabPanel(HTML("<span style='font-size:120%'>Page A</span>"),        
      h4("Table is shown below: ",style="font-size: 20px"),
      helpText("The ** sign means the sample size is less than 5.",style="font-size:16px"),
      h3("Demand no. - based.",style="font-size:16px"),
      h3("Demand rate - based.",style="font-size:16px"),),

tabPanel(HTML("<span style='font-size:120%'>Table_inquire</span>"),
     h4("Table is shown below: ",style="font-size: 20px"),
     h3("Demand no. - based.",style="font-size:16px"),
     h3("Demand rate - based.",style="font-size:16px"),
     h3("Recommended model:",style="font-size:16px"),),


server:
  output$download_predict_batch <- downloadHandler(
filename = function() {
  paste("output_batch_predict.xlsx")
},
content = function(file) {
  dataset_names <- list('Demand no. - based.' = output_table_predict, 'Demand rate - based.' = output_table_predict)
  write.xlsx(dataset_names, file, rowNames = FALSE)
  
}
```

)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure could you use one download button to download tables from different tab panels. Below is a minimal reproducible example on how to achieve that. First you have to add an `id` to the `tabsetPanel`. Second, for convenience add a `value` to the `tabPanel`s  to identify which tab is selected. Inside the server you could then use two `reactive`s to set the filename and the data to be exported depending on which tab is selected:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      downloadButton("download_predict_batch", "Download")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = "tabs",
        tabPanel(
          HTML("<span style='font-size:120%'>Page A</span>"),
          h4("Table is shown below: ", style = "font-size: 20px"),
          value = "tab1"
        ),
        tabPanel(
          HTML("<span style='font-size:120%'>Table_inquire</span>"),
          h4("Table is shown below: ", style = "font-size: 20px"),
          value = "tab2"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  fn <- reactive({
    if (input$tabs == "tab1") {
      "output_batch_predict.xlsx"
    } else {
      "part.xlsx"
    }
  })

  dataset_names <- reactive({
    if (input$tabs == "tab1") {
      list("Demand no. - based." = mtcars, "Demand rate - based." = mtcars)
    } else {
      list("Demand no. - based." = iris, "Demand rate - based." = iris)
    }
  })

  output$download_predict_batch <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      fn()
    },
    content = function(file) {
      openxlsx::write.xlsx(dataset_names(), file, rowNames = FALSE)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4685
```

[image]